# Transact data to smart contract on Ethereum with SAME wallet key on local machine via script

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I am planning to accept data from people not having knowledge of 'public/private keys and ethereum', and I want to transact this data to my already deployed smart contract on ethereum blockchain.

I cannot use web3 as users won't have any ethereum wallet. This condition is a requirement in my case.

How can I put data on contract:
Example scenario: Greeter contract with get() and set().

I just want to run automatically a script everytime some data is posted to my server so that this data is transacted to Greeter contract in set(). Always with my same public/private key pair.

Any suggestions or dummy script would help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
const express = require("express");
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// The contract ABI
let abi = [
    {
        constant: true,
        inputs: [],
        name: "get",
        outputs: [{ internalType: "uint256", name: "", type: "uint256" }],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function"
    },
    {
        constant: false,
        inputs: [{ internalType: "uint256", name: "x", type: "uint256" }],
        name: "set",
        outputs: [],
        payable: false,
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "function"
    }
];

// Connect to contract
// https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x00530Aae5fDFa2C4cFe21Df5Fbe1B2213fe8f551#code
let provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider("goerli");
let contractAddress = "0x00530Aae5fDFa2C4cFe21Df5Fbe1B2213fe8f551";
let contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);

app.get("/:message", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        userInput = req.params.message;
        console.log("User input:", userInput); // if it prints 'favicon.ico', that's normal
        userNumber = parseInt(userInput);

        // Make sure user input is a number
        if (isNaN(userNumber)) {
            return res.send("Please only send number").end();
        }

        // Do not store private key in code
        let privateKey = fs
            .readFileSync("private-key.txt")
            .toString()
            .trim();
        let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
        let contractWithSigner = contract.connect(wallet);
        let tx = await contractWithSigner.set(userNumber);

        res.send(
            `Tx with number '${userNumber}' has been sent to contract.\nHash: ${tx.hash}.`
        );

        // When the tx has been mined, you can verify it here:
        // https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x00530aae5fdfa2c4cfe21df5fbe1b2213fe8f551#readContract
    } catch (error) {
        return next(error);
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App is listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Please refer to [this repository](https://gitlab.com/zulhfreelancer/keyless-ethereum-tx) for full source code. Contract can be found [here](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x00530Aae5fDFa2C4cFe21Df5Fbe1B2213fe8f551#code).